# Undefine/Unset newcolumntype to use tabulary with tablestyles

Tags: tables, arrays, tabulary

In a project I'm working on I'm using the latex package Tablestyles for styling tables. Until now I have been using tabularx for tables. However, now I need tabulary for automatically setting the column width based on the target width of the table. When including tabulary naively with tablestyles I get an error.

File contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{tabularx} % tablestyles requires tabularx
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|}
    \theadstart
    \thead a & \thead b \\
    \tbody
    1 & One\\
    2 & Two\\
    \tend
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everysel/everysel-2011-10-28.sty)
))

Package array Warning: Column W is already defined on input line 264.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabulary/tabulary.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./main.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   |
l.28 \end{tabulary}
```

I have done some debugging and I have edited a local copy of tablestyles. I commented the following columntype definitions in tablestyles.dtx since I do not use them in my project:

tablestyles.dtx lines 1619 to 1630

```
%% centered (X):
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
%% right (X):
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
%% left (X):
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
%% left (p):
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%% right (p):
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%% centered (p):
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
```

Then I can successfully compile my program and the tabulary works with the tablestyles:

[image]

Instead of using my own copy of tablestyles, I would like to undefine the columntypes in tablestyles before loading tabulary, something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\removecolumntype{Z}
\removecolumntype{Y}
\removecolumntype{W}
\removecolumntype{L}
\removecolumntype{R}
\removecolumntype{C}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
```

But for as far as I know, no such function exists, nor can I determine from the source of the `array` package how to reverse the effects of `\newcolumntype`. Maybe someone can help me achieve this, or provide another way of using tabulary with tablestyles. An alternative to tabulary for automatically determining the right column width is also appreciated.

Comment: generally speaking, fixing package incompatibility is always difficult. have you considered simply copy-pasting the content of the tablestyles.sty file into the TeX file?

Comment: if the packages are under active maintenance there's also the option of contacting (emailing?) the author so they fix the incompatibility/provide option

Comment: the error isn't really due to tabulary the array package that defines `\newcolumntype` has defined a `W` column for some years (since 2017) `tablestyles` really should be updated not to overwrite that.

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't really due to `tabulary`: the `array` package that defines `\newcolumntype` has defined a `W` column for some years (since 2017) `tablestyles` really should be updated not to overwrite that.

`tablestyles` seems to be a collection of more or less unrelated shortcut commands for tables, so I'd be tempted simply to not load it but copy the commands that you use from that package, but if you would rather load it, as all the offending `\newcolumnype` are at the end, you can locally force `\newcolumntype` to stop the package load at that point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}

\let\oldnewcolumntype\newcolumntype
\def\newcolumntype#1#2{\endinput}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\let\newcolumntype\oldnewcolumntype


\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|}
    \theadstart
    \thead a & \thead b \\
    \tbody
    1 & One\\
    2 & Two\\
    \tend
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

---

You don't normally need anything like `\removecolumntype` as a `\newcolumntype` doesn't actually have to be new: you can redefine an existing column if it was defined  via `\newcolumnype`. However you can not define columns with the same names as the built-in `array` package column names (as this would generate infinite loops) and since 2017 that has included `W` so this is basically an error in the package that should be reported to the maintainer.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response. I will report the issue to the maintainer. In the mean time I can use the redefinition fix you provided.

Comment: The issue is not completely due to the W column though. I have tried commenting out all \newcolumntype except `L` (which I use in the tabulary table) and it still gives the problem which is printed at the end of the log output I provided.

Comment: Another question, your solution works, but redefining the command to `\relax` like this: `def\newcolumntype#1#2{\relax}` gives me a "missing begin document" error. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Jan-JaapKorpershoek that's why I used the form I used:-)  You would need a more elaborate definition: some uses in the package have `{..}[1]{..}` so more than just two arguments to eat.

Comment: You need to commen out `L` as well, as `tabulary` defins L by newcolumnype so if you load this package after tabulary then L gets redefined as I comment in the main answer so tabulary is essentially disabled. so the package defining W is an error the package defining L is simply a choice of the package that L should mean its definition not the tabulary L, that is unfortunate for your use case but not an error as such..